# Kentico 13: Getting the current document when registering custom macro fields

Tags: kentico

Normally in order to get the current document in K13, we must use DI to get the `IPageDataContextRetriever`.

However, when trying to register a custom macro field, adding a constructor to my class (in order to use DI) prevents the class from registering:

```
[assembly: RegisterExtension(typeof(MyMacroFields), typeof(TreeNode))]
public class MyMacroFields : MacroFieldContainer, IService
{
    public const string TitleMacro = "MyMetaTitle";
    public const string DescriptionMacro = "MyMetaDescription";

    private readonly IPageDataContextRetriever _pageDataContextRetriever;

    public MyMacroFields(IPageDataContextRetriever pageDataContextRetriever)
    {
        _pageDataContextRetriever = pageDataContextRetriever;
    }

    protected override void RegisterFields()
    {
        base.RegisterFields();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use DI somehow? Or is there another way to get the current document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a how to article here that solves the issue:

https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/building-an-integration-(stripe)-part-3-helpers-and-event-handlers